# Strange behavior with slash and backslash in file paths

Tags: java, windows, file, backslash, slash

We are having wierd issues when working with paths in Java for files. The thing is that sometimes, when working in Windows, operations with files created with slashes and backslashes in their paths are failing. As a rule we are replacing slashes by backslashes bu we cannot identify why sometimes the operation fails and others not.

Specifically the operation is file.delete(). It does not throw any kind of Exception, if simply fails.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You don't need to replace slashes with backslashes, on any platform. Just remove that code.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn’t use `File.delete()` for exactly the reason you have described; it doesn’t provide you with a meaningful response if the operation fails.

Use [`Files.delete(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) or [`Files.deleteIfExists(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists(java.nio.file.Path)) to delete a file (denoted by a `Path`, see [`Paths.get(String…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) and [`File.toPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath())) as these methods will throw a meaningful `IOException` on failure whereas only the latter returns a `boolean` which will indicate success or non-existence but all other conditions are flagged with an exception.

There are indeed functions in the Windows API which silently handle slashes as separators but since it is not specified which Java API methods will use which native functions, you can’t rely on any particular behavior in this regard. You should always use the separator as indicated by [`File.separatorChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) or `FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()` when using the `nio` API.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you escape backslashes, Java treats them as escape codes. This is how newline (`\n`) and tab (`\t`) work, for example.

From the [JavaDoc on Characters and Escape Sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html):

> A character preceded by a backslash (`\`) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.

So what's happening is that your file path is probably something that's being treated as an escape sequence. That link has some detail as to what kinds of escape codes there are.

So if you just did this:

```
  File.delete("c:\this.txt")
  // Converted to "c:      his.txt" (because of the tab)
```

I'd recommend either doubling up the backslashes (`\\`) or going to all forward slashes, if you can.

Comment: actually, it's "c:              his.txt"

Answer (score 0):

`File.delete` does not throw an exception if it fails; instead it returns a boolean that indicates whether the delete has failed or not. From the Javadoc:

> Returns `true` if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted; `false` otherwise

If you *want* an exception when the delete fails, you need to raise it yourself:

```
if (!myfile.delete()) {
     throw new IOException("Couldn't delete file " + myfile.getPath());
}
```